# Merge branch into multiple brances

Tags: git

I have a change in a branch A i want to merge to multiple branches master, B and C, what's the best approach ?

Merge branch into master then merge master into the other branches (B and C) or merge the branch A with the change into each branch master, B and C ? The reason i ask is that i want to make sure there is no problems when i merge these branches (B and C) back to master.

If i merge branch A into master i get a merge commit which is fine. If i now merge master into B and C i point at the merge commit and i merge the branch A dirrectly into B and C there is one commit less. Is both ways equal good ? Ofcourse i assume that there is no other changes in master that i don't want to get into my branch B and C if i choose to merge from master -> Branch B and C.

donnib